# Itext - Adding image in header - Empy Chunk

Tags: itext

I'm trying to add an image to a `PdfPageEventHelper` class, as i saw in the original documentation, but when trying to add the new Chunk with the image to a Phrase, it's always empty...

This is my header and footer class

```
class PDFHeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

        public PDFHeaderFooter() throws BadElementException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
            super();

        }

        Image image = Image.getInstance(imagesDir + "logo.png");
        Phrase header = new Phrase(new Chunk(image, 0, 0, true));
        int pagenumber;

        public void onChapter(PdfWriter writer, Document document, float paragraphPosition, Paragraph title) {

            pagenumber = 1;
        }

        public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            pagenumber++;
        }

        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
            logger.debug(header.getContent());

            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header, rect.getRight(),
                    rect.getTop(), 0);

            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                    new Phrase(String.format("pag. %d", pagenumber), fontSize9), (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2,
                    rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
        }



    }
```

If i try to add the image in the document body, there is no problem at all, it's just when trying to add it the support class... is there another way?
thanks

Comment: Did my answer help or are there still open points? I wonder because of your total lack of response.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue is that `ColumnText.showTextAligned` uses a `ColumnText` instance with a column rectangle only three units high.

The `ColumnText` code is designed to output one line of text at its preferred height (usually exceeding the 3 units) anyways in such a case. Most likely this is a hack to make `ColumnText.showTextAligned` work for a single line of text.

Unfortunately the `ColumnText` code at the same time scales down images in chunks to that 3 unit available column height, making them hardly more than dirt specks, or alternatively even drops them.

For phrases containing image chunks, therefore, one should not use the `ColumnText.showTextAligned` convenience methods but instead explicitly use a `ColumnText` instance with a sensible column rectangle height, e.g. replace

```java
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header, rect.getRight(),
        rect.getTop()-30, 0);
```

by

```java
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
ct.setSimpleColumn(header, rect.getLeft(), rect.getTop(30), rect.getRight(), rect.getTop(), 2, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
try {
    ct.go();
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
}
```

*([AddHeaderImage](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/AddHeaderImage.java#L148) page event listener method `onEndPage`)*

It's not so much less convenient, after all, and one has more influence on the layout'ing details...